# How to determine which foreign key constraint failed?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with two foreign keys. The error code is ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2 no matter which foreign key failed. Is there a way to tell which foreign key constraint failed?

Comment: Check the error message instead of error code

Comment: the error message just provides some location like `#sql-9f9_7` but what does that mean

Answer (score 0):

Rename the indexing for the foreign key and you will get the name of the field in **e.driverError.sqlMessage**